# Haskell-mode "could not find module"

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I am following an Asteroids tutorial in Haskell([Haskeroids](https://github.com/shangaslammi/haskeroids/wiki)) and I'm having a problem with my submodules. Basically, my folder structure is like this:

```
project/
|-- main.hs
|-- Haskeroids/
    |-- Geometry.hs
    |-- Geometry/
        |-- Transform.hs
```

The Geometry.hs file has

```
module Haskeroids.Geometry where
```

while the Transform.hs file has

```
module Haskeroids.Geometry.Transform where
import Haskeroids.Geometry
```

for some reason, ghc seems to look for Geometry/Haskeroids/Geometry.hs.
is there some setting to set so that ghc knows where to look for the file, and what is the way to set it for haskell-mode?

Edit: the error message was: Could not find module Haskeroids.Geometry. Use - v to see a list of the files searched

Comment: please post the entire error message...

Comment: I guess you have a cabal project - did you list all the modules in there?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the project you linked to and inspected the cabal file - as I suggested you are not mentioning Haskeroids stuff there.

```
 ..

Executable haskeroids
    Main-is:            main.hs

    Other-modules:      Haskeroids.Geometry
                 ,      Haskeroids.Geometry.Transform

    Build-Depends:      base >= 4, transformers >= 0.2.2.0,
                        ...
```

add the `Other-modules` part to your cabal file and everything should work well and dandy.

Comment: I would also advise you to use `cabal` or `stack` to build your executable instead of calling ghc directly (via build.bat)

Comment: Ah thank you. I don't have much experience with cabal/stack so i wouldn't have known.